# Trouble with output JSON in Nest API

Tags: json, nest-api

Recently I've started to work with Nest API. I've added a thermostat and make a call to NEST API to retrieve thermostat details. I've create a Java model According to [Nest API Documentation](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference). But I've noticed that some of the fields are missed - **last_connection**. Same thing with 'smoke_co_alarms' devices - **last_connection**, **battery_health**, **co_alarm_state**, **smoke_alarm_state**, **ui_color_state** - these fields are missed in Nest API response.

Tried to google this question - no results. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: are you using the simulator or real devices? Also are you using a parsing library?

Comment: @urman: I'm using a simulator - I have added virtual devices in simulator. After that I call NEST API endpoint "/devices" (using Advanced REST client) to see devices I've added before. As a result I can see JSON described here - https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference. But some of the fields are missed.

Comment: have you logged into home.nest.com? login there and make sure that the state is changing there as well as the simulator.

Comment: @urman: yes, I'm logged in home.nest.com. Thermostat's state is changed as well as simulator. But when I make API call to NEST API to retrieve info about thermostat I received JSON where 'last_connection' field is missed.

Comment: Is it only the last_connection field? You mentioned battery_health, co_alarm_state, smoke_alarm_state, ui_color_state as well

Comment: @urman: last_connection field is missed for both - thermostat & smoke_co_alarms devices. 
battery_health & ui_color_state are missed for smoke_co_alarms. 
But co_alarm_state & smoke_alarm_state started to be visible in response from REST API call.

Comment: @urman: now, I have real thermostat, I've added it to my account and now I can see last_connection field in response. Looks like I need real device to see this field. I suppose that battery_health & ui_color_state fields also will be available for real connected device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've connected real thermostat, added it to my account and now I can see **last_connection** field in response. Looks like I need to CONNECT REAL DEVICE to see this field. I suppose that **battery_health** & **ui_color_state** fields also will be available for real connected device.